# Regex to match reocurring character groups

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regex that would match groups of exactly three characters, that reoccur within the text at least one time.
What I came up with is this simple regex:`(.{3}).*\g1`, using the \g (global) and \s (dot also matches newline) flags. However, it is clearly faulty, as it only finds a part of the groups I'm hoping to capture. Any idea how can I improve it? Here is the link to an example input https://regex101.com/r/Cuiva1/2
Edit: Here's the full list of groups I was hoping to capture as requested in the comment:`GLT`,`VIW`,`IWK`,`KTL`,`GLT`,`LTK`,`LIS`,`KTX`,`TXK`,`XDL`,`KTL`

Comment: What do you mean, "clearly faulty"? What's wrong with the results?

Comment: You could use `(.{3})(?=.*\g1)` but this still won't match overlapping groups.

Comment: @melpomene It doesn't capture every group that satisfies the conditions I provided, for example it should capture the "VIW" in the link I provided, as it contains "VIWKTLVIW"

Comment: What exactly is the expected output for your example input?

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad, I posted a link to the older one, updating the thread with correct link right now

Comment: Do you need to get overlapping groups? E.g., `ABC` and `BCD` from `ABCDXXXABCYYYBCDZZZ`? Then `(?=(...)).(?=...*?\g1)` does the trick. Otherwise, the regex @SebastianProske gave above is enough.

Comment: Why use `\g1` if `\1` is already the backreference to the first group value? [`(?=(.{3})(?=.*\1))`](https://regex101.com/r/DLnYdE/1) actually returns 10 matches vs. [`(.{3})(?=.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/DLnYdE/2) (7 only).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, paulotorrens and SebastianProske I actually don't need the overlapping and the first one did the trick, however it's really nice to also know how to handle the harder case

Comment: Please add all necessary clarifications to the question, otherwise, it is just unclear what your requirements are. (See *a part of the groups I'm hoping to capture* - what groups are those?)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always multiple triplets of uppercase characters and you're only looking for ones that repeat, then you need something more complex to avoid backtracking into a previous triplet:

```
 /(?>[^A-Z]*+([A-Z]{3}))(?=(?:[^A-Z]*+[A-Z]{3})*?\1)|(?>[^A-Z]*+[A-Z]{3})/g
```

The matches from index `1` will hold what you want. If your strings are not that well formatted (i.e. may contain any length string in between repeating patterns, then you can use a simpler pattern but you'll get totally inconsistent results and miss some matches.

---

I re-read your desired output, you're not going to achieve this with regex. `VIW` and `IWK` are overlapping, which won't work in a single `preg_match_all()`. Just use string functions.